# loop through stepper headers and add dividers except for the last item

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using the [stepper component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/steppers) and instead of hardcoding the headers and the content I loop through an array of objects.

The stepper items work really fine with

```
<v-stepper-items>
  <v-stepper-content
    v-for="(step, stepIndex) in steps"
    :key="stepIndex"
    :step="stepIndex"
  >
    <component :is="step.content"/>
  </v-stepper-content>
</v-stepper-items>
```

The headers get tricky. Between those headers should be a divider component but this breaks the CSS when I wrap both in a wrapping element. The last item should not add a divider.

```
<v-stepper-header>
  <v-container v-for="(step, stepIndex) in steps" :key="stepIndex">
    <v-stepper-step :complete="currentStep > stepIndex" :step="stepIndex">
      {{step.header}}
    </v-stepper-step>
    <v-divider :v-if="stepIndex < steps.length - 1"></v-divider>
  </v-container>
</v-stepper-header>
```

How can I loop through those stepper headers without wrapping them in a container / breaking the CSS?

---

**Update**

Here is a small codepen showing the CSS problem. The `v-container` component breaks it.

https://codepen.io/pdntspa/pen/ZEYOZOP?editors=1010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a template tag such as `<template v-for="(header, index) in headers">`, the template tag is not displayed in HTML and will not affect your layout, you can even add another template tag wrapping the whole thing with a `v-if` condition if you need to.

**HTML** :

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-stepper v-model="e1">
      <v-stepper-header>
        <template v-for="(header, index) in headers">
          <v-stepper-step :step="index + 1">{{ header }}</v-stepper-step>
          <v-divider v-if="index < headers.length - 1"/>
        </template>
      </v-stepper-header>
      <v-stepper-items>
        <v-stepper-content step="1">
          <v-card
            class="mb-12"
            color="grey lighten-1"
            height="200px"
          ></v-card>
          <v-btn
            color="primary"
            @click="e1 = 2"
          >
            Continue
          </v-btn>
          <v-btn text>Cancel</v-btn>
        </v-stepper-content>
        <v-stepper-content step="2">
          <v-card
            class="mb-12"
            color="grey lighten-1"
            height="200px"
          ></v-card>
          <v-btn
            color="primary"
            @click="e1 = 3"
          >
            Continue
          </v-btn>
          <v-btn text>Cancel</v-btn>
        </v-stepper-content>

        <v-stepper-content step="3">
          <v-card
            class="mb-12"
            color="grey lighten-1"
            height="200px"
          ></v-card>
          <v-btn
            color="primary"
            @click="e1 = 1"
          >
            Continue
          </v-btn>
          <v-btn text>Cancel</v-btn>
        </v-stepper-content>
      </v-stepper-items>
    </v-stepper>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

**JS** :

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      e1: 0,
      headers: [
        'Step 1',
        'Step 2',
        'Step 3',
        'Step 4'
      ]
    }
  },
})
```

Here's a [fork of your codepen](https://codepen.io/Jakensen/pen/jOErRye?editors=1010#anon-signup) as well.

A small warning though, your `<v-divider>` condition wasn't / isn't working due to the extra and unneeded colon before your v-if : `:v-if`

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your help. I have to set keys for the steps and the dividers because `template` can't be keyed. Somehow your fix always starts at step 1 although the `currentStep` returns 0. I updated the fork, do you know what's wrong? https://codepen.io/pdntspa/pen/zYxBQVR?editors=1010

Comment: Since we want it to start at step 1 we have to modify the currentStep value as well as the stepIndex value. You had two extra colons on your v-btn's v-if again, watch out for these. Here's a working fork of your latest pen : https://codepen.io/Jakensen/pen/jOErjeY?editors=1010